# Add a different drop down for each line in a Suitlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm making a Suitelet with a sublist with different lines.
In one column, I have a dropdown that I create with *Sublist.addField(option)*
I know that we can add options with:

```
selectField.addSelectOption({
    value : '',
    text : ''
});
```

But the options will be the same for each line.
Is there a way to have different options per line?

Comment: Good question, but I guess there is no such option. You can file an enhancement. Maybe within 20 years, they will look at it..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lines perhaps you want fieldgroups and in each fieldgroup you can make it have a group name displayed or not.

In each row you can have similar fields at same position/column position but you'll have more flexibility.  They will be different fields (and scriptids) but you can have them named as such so that when you submit you can parse the parameters easily.